# Creating MySQL Table with fitting Date Format dd/MMM/yyyy:hh:mm:ss Z

Tags: mysql, sql, date

So I am trying to create a mysql table with JDBC.
In this table I want a column in which the following timestamp should fit:

01/Nov./2018:12:01:43 +0100
This is in the Format: dd/MMM/yyyy:hh:mm:ss Z

//--------------------- EDIT
Now this SQL Statement creates my table successfully:

```
 "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `FilteredLogs` ("
 + "id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,"
 + "`TIME` DATETIME," 
 + "`IP` varchar(20) NOT NULL," 
 + "`USER` varchar(1000) NOT NULL," 
 + "`URI` varchar(1000) NOT NULL," 
 + "`STATUS` INT NOT NULL)";
```

Now I try to put Data into the table:

```
        PreparedStatement input = con.prepareStatement("insert into "+tableName+"(TIME, IP, USER, URI, STATUS) values(?,?,?,?,?);");

        input.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(formattime));
        input.setString(2, iplog);
        input.setString(3, userlog);
        input.setString(4, urilog);
        input.setInt(5, statuslog);
        input.execute();
```

This throws an IllegalArgumentException with "formattime" being a String with value: "01/Nov/2018:00:00:17 +0100"

Answer (score 0):

Your `TIME` column  date type will be `DATETIME` not just `date` and use format in times of data presentation

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `FilteredLogs` ("
 + "id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, "
 + "`TIME` DATETIME " 
 + "`IP` varchar(20) NOT NULL, " 
 + "`USER` varchar(1000) NOT NULL, " 
 + "`URI` varchar(1000) NOT NULL, " 
 + "`STATUS` INT NOT NULL"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Sadly I am still getting the same SQL Exception at the same point

Comment: But this colon is there. There is no space between the yyy and hh in my String. EDIT: Also I just tested it without the colon and space between just like you suggest. But it still doesnt work.

Comment: @marcels93 you have to use format in times of data showing

Comment: Thank you! Now I am facing a problem when I try to insert the Date into the created table. I edited my Question

Comment: i answered your 1st question its supposed to be different question